# Addition of multiple autocorrect substitution words to excel in one shot?

Tags: excel, ms-office

On my home PC, I have MS Office 2007. I use excel regularly and have a large number of autocorrect substitution words added to the language list. Is there some way I can import that list into another the MS Office for my office, which is a different PC? Is there some import/export option for this?

Comment: Export from android to MS-Office would also be ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Excel `File` => `Options` => `Proofing`=>`Custom Dictionaries`. You can add additional dictionaries there.

Tried to find some non VBA solution but it seems like there isn't one. what you could try is to put all your autocorrect words in `Sheet1`, Column `A` containing word to correct, and column `B` containing corrected word. then try this code

```
Sub AddAutocorect()
For x = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Application.AutoCorrect.AddReplacement Range("A" & x).Value, Range("B" & x).Value
Next x
End Sub
```

This code should add all autocorect values without the need for manual data entry.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

I use a large number of Autocorrect substitutions in Microsoft Word. I find that I can copy them from one machine to another by simply copying %appdata%\Microsoft\Office\MSO1033.acl. I also keep a copy of that file as a backup, to restore whenever I reinstall or repair Windows.

This is in Windows 10. I think the folder may have been the same in Windows 7.

[Various blog posts](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&ei=SoRCYI22B4aQtAbFq6qADw&q=mso1033.acl%20macro%20site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fraywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com%2F%20OR%20site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fraywoodcockslatest.blogspot.com%2F&oq=mso1033.acl%20macro%20site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fraywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com%2F%20OR%20site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fraywoodcockslatest.blogspot.com%2F&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAxQAFgAYLiEA2gAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiNg9C475nvAhUGCM0KHcWVCvAQ4dUDCAw) explore related activities. For instance, I think I used a macro to empty out the list of substitutions, before adding new ones, so that my MSO1033.acl backup would not contain the same unwanted definitions, originally provided by Microsoft.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.